# How to show that $\mathcal P(\Bbb N)\sim\mathcal P(\Bbb N)^\Bbb N$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I am trying to proof now that $\mathcal P(\Bbb N)$ is of the same cardinality as $\mathcal P(\Bbb N)^\Bbb N$ - the set of all functions $f:\Bbb N\to\mathcal P(\Bbb N)$.
Currently I've tried to use the knowledge that: $\mathcal P(\Bbb N)\sim \{0,1\}^\Bbb N$ but it doesn't help much.
Also, I've proved that: $\left(A^B\right)^C \sim A^{B\times C}$.

Any ideas how to continue? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

**HINT:** Note that from the last thing you mention it follows that $\left(\{0,1\}^\Bbb N\right)^\Bbb N=\{0,1\}^{\Bbb{N\times N}}$, and that $\Bbb{N\sim N\times N}$.